# Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 Cache Channel Server - Setup

Tags: tridion

Just wanted to check as the after reading docs I'm not 100% sure but in our scenario we have a separate server with running the Deployer (HTTP Upload), a separate SQL Server with Broker on it and two presentation servers each with the API server role installed.

We want to take advantage of Tridion Object caching so

On each presentation server:

1. Installed CCS.
2. Update cd_storage_conf:

   - ObjectCache enabled = true
   - Add RemoteSynchronization entry pointing to the local Cache Channel service "localhost".
   - Set cached=true on ItemTypes I want to cache.

On Deployer server:

1. CCS not installed here.
2. Update cd_storage_conf:

   - ObjectCache enabled = true
   - Add RemoteSynchronization entry pointing to each of the Cache Channel services on the presentation servers.
   - Set cached=true on ItemTypes I want to cache.

I this correct? 
Basically I'm unsure if the CCS goes on each API server to be notified by the Deployer, or if it goes on the Deployer server and the API server point to it there?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not correct. You only need one CCS. I normally place this on the server running the Deployer. Then the Brokers on the application servers running your websites subscribe to the CCS which notifies them when to delete items from the cache.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. You may notice that the CCS is a single point of failure (SPOF) in this architecture. If that worries you, check out the alternative, JMS. I described it here: http://blog.trivident.com/2012/09/tridion-and-jms-removing-another-spof/.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I am aware that is the correct set up. If I understand correctly [this](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=publist_home#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&lang=&action=search&query=cache%2520channel%2520service&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1359107472680&currentQuery=cache%2520channel%2520service&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_B4F723510F174B499297C4DB711D95E8&pubid=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&publang=en-US&resource=&docid=task_B4F723510F174B499297C4DB711D95E8&filename=SynchronizingCachesUsingRMI.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&inner_id=&addHistory=true) you only need to install CCS on one server and then point from the other CD servers to the one with CCS installed.

Comment: Ah - OK. Then CCS would only need to be installed on my Deployer server and the other servers pointed to it - NOT the other way around, (where each CD server has an instance of CCS on it)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.